# Астрономические названия

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Прочитала, что при написании "галактика Млечный Путь" можно вместо полного названия писать *Галактика*.
Тогда можно ли вместо "планета Земля", "планета Марс" писать *Планета* или *наша Планета*?

Comment: Не очень понятно, почему галактика нужно писать с большой буквы. Писать-то можно хоть все слова с большой, но зачем?

Comment: Читала, что в значении "наша Галактика", "моя Галактика" можно писать Галактика. Одним словом

Comment: В общем, судя по всему галактика - это и есть слово "млечный", но по-гречески. И поначалу это было название Млечного Пути. Галактика = Млечный Путь. Но в последующем галактика стало номинальным названием для скоплений звезд. Возможно поэтому иногда пишут наша Галактика, что по сути значит наш Млечный Путь. Будет ли тавтологией употребления Галактика Млечный Путь - не знаю. Однако, с планетами такое не прокатит, потому что планета - это изначально класс небесных тел, а не название какой-то конкретной планеты. Это как Земля и сказать земля при виде другой планеты, назвать её землей.

Comment: Есть и другие галактики, например, галактика Андромеда

Comment: Ну да, есть, но о них узнали после того, как поняли что "Млечный" - это наша Галактика. Потом просто всех обозвали тоже галактиками, это как другие планеты обозвать землями, но Земля - это наша планета, она - одна. И писать Галактика Андромеда - уже ошибка, скорее всего. Ну или это какой-то очень поэтический текст.

Comment: И в литературных произведениях те же нюансы?.. Интересует художественный текст

Comment: Не могу сказать, за неимением текста, ничего. Но, если в общем, то могу повторить только: Земля - наша планета, Галактика - наша галактика, она же Млечный Путь, что суть тоже самое название только с добавкой "путь"; а другая планета - это земля с маленькой буквы, как и любая другая галактика.

Comment: "Поприветствуем наших путешественников с галактики Млечный Путь!" - сказали ведущие. 
"Благодарим всех, кто пришел! Мы приехали с севера Галактики на ваш праздник и очень этому рады!" - ответили путешественники.

Comment: В публицистике и научно-популярной литературе могут использоваться синонимические термины — *мир, **голубая планета**, Терра*.

Comment: "Поприветствуем наших(?) путешественников Млечного Пути!" - я бы убрал галактику и предлог "из", если оставить галактику, то не ясно, почему галактика то с маленькой, то в внезапно с большой, также не ясно почему "наших", если они из другой галактики по отношению к приветствующим. Далее... "мы приехали(? может прилетели) с севера (тоже очень странное направление, ввиду того, что север, это направление от Земли к Полярной звезде, к галактике это не относится, у галактики направления севера нет и в космосе трехмерная сетка координат, а не двумерный крест.

Comment: Также последнее путешественники лучше уточнить, потому что повторение не увеличивает художественную ценность, нужно что-то новенькое.

Comment: "Поприветствуем наших *дорогих гостей*, путешественников Млечного Пути! - сказали ведущие(чего? или какие? не стоит скупиться на детали). "Благодарим всех, кто пришел(нас встретить)! (тут тоже нужны детали по описанию встречи или еще чего-то, впечатления путешественников, чем больше деталей, тем интереснее) Мы приехали из области, которая у нас называется  "Север Галактики(можно любой топоним+детали)" на праздник(лучше название праздника или обстоятельства) и очень этому рады быть здесь со всеми вами!" - ответили путешественники(детали).

Comment: Это конструкция была придумана только для того, чтобы показать, как слово "Галактика" может быть написано с заглавной буквы. Можно не обращать внимания на смысл, логику или художественное благозвучие

Answer (score 4):

В орфографическом словаре:
**Гала́ктика**, -и (*звездная система, к которой принадлежит Солнце*)
и **гала́ктика**,  -и (*о звездных системах*).

В толковом словаре:
[**галактика**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), -и; ***ж.*** [от греч. *galaktikós* — молочный, млечный]
**1.** *[с прописной буквы] **только ед.*** Звёздная система, к которой принадлежит Солнце; система Млечного Пути. *Наша Галактика.*
**2. *обычно мн.***: галактики, -тик. Звёздные системы Вселенной.

Из журнала "Наука и жизнь":

> Еще через какое-то время астрономы обнаружили, что у **нашей Галактики** есть соседи, что туманность Андромеды, Большое Магелланово Облако, Малое Магелланово Облако и многие другие туманные пятнышки — это уже не **наша Галактика**, а другие, самостоятельные звездные острова.

Из [школьной энциклопедии](https://crazylike.ru/beautiful-names-for-galaxies-list-school-encyclopedia.html):

> Выражение «галактика Млечный Путь», по сути, тавтология. Galactikos в примерном переводе с древнегреческого означает «молочный». Так жители Пелопоннеса звали скопление звезд в ночном небе, приписывая его происхождение вспыльчивой Гере... Спустя столетия ученые открыли, что наблюдаемые светила — лишь ничтожная часть существующих небесных тел. Пространству Вселенной, в котором находится и **наша планета**, они дали название **Галактика** или система Млечный Путь. После подтверждения предположения о существовании и других схожих формирований в космосе первый термин стал для них универсальным.
> <...>
> Тот факт, что Земля — элемент системы Млечный Путь, накладывает определенные ограничения на тех, кто пытается выяснить, какую форму имеет **наша Галактика**.
> <...>
> Собранные сведения позволяют с уверенностью говорить, что **наша Галактика** имеет форму диска с утолщением (балджем) в середине и расходящимися от центра спиральными рукавами.

Для планет, в том числе и для Земли (*планета Земля → наша Планета*?), таких рекомендаций нет, поэтому пишем со строчной (ну... если только не используем особый, высокий стиль):

*Некоторые ученые говорят, что **наша планета** находится в «зоне лютиков». Как связана эта зона с жизнью  на Земле?* (олимпиада по космической биологии);
"Жизнь на **нашей планете**" (название документального фильма);
*Вместе с Солнцем **наша планета** вращается вокруг **центра Галактики** со скоростью 240 км/с и совершает полный оборот вокруг него за 180 млн лет* (из учебника).