# «Галактика-спутник» или «галактика-спутник»?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Я знаю, что *галактика* пишется с маленькой буквы, если после стоит название Галактики: *галактика Млечный Путь*, *галактика GN-z11*, НО! *Размер нашей Галактики, Млечный Путь, 107 000 св. лет* — *Млечный Путь* — уточнение. А также если употреблено во мн. числе, то есть *галактики*, *галактик*. В остальных случаях с прописной. Но как насчет *(г, Г)алактика-спутник*? Какая буква первая: прописная или строчная? И скажите, верна ли пунктуация и орфография в моем вопросе (естественно, укажите на ошибки и исправьте)?

[Изменения в тексте вопроса показаны в ответе. — Р. М.]

Comment: Галактика - это в переводе с греческого "Млечный". То есть Галактика - это собственно название нашей галактики Млечный Путь. То есть галактика - это нарицательное для класса скоплений звезд, а Галактика - это только наша галактика Млечный Путь. Поэтому галактика-спутник не требует никаких особенных написаний в русском языке. В логике английского может быть иначе. С планетами, астероидами такого не происходит. Хотя Луна - это земная луна.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474485/Астрономические-названия - вот вопрос на эту же тему, был пару недель назад.

Comment: @Максим Спасибо, Максим, за принятие моего ответа. Значит, он помог решить вашу проблему. Скажите, а почему вы не отмечаете *полезность* ответов и вопросов (то есть не голосуете треугольничком сверху) — не только своих, но и других участников? Это ведь тоже повышает репутацию отвечающего (+10), стимулирует его, показывает заинтересованность в получении правильного ответа.

Comment: Я не знал, что так можно. Теперь сделал. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Правильно с маленькой буквы: [**галактика-спутник**](https://orthography.academic.ru/4813/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) (именно так написано в справочнике "Слитно. Раздельно. Через дефис" Б. З. Букчиной и в орфографических словарях).

Именно такой вывод можно сделать и из ответа на нашем сайте ([Астрономические названия](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474485/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)):
с большой буквы пишется только звёздная система, к которой принадлежит Солнце.

*Многие **галактики-спутники** Млечного Пути были обнаружены в рамках проекта Dark Energy Survey (2013—2019 годы), целью которого был поиск темной материи и темной энергии* (из статьи).

•• Шапка: * (г, Г)алактика-спутник *.
Я бы написала так: «Галактика-спутник» или «галактика-спутник»?
В заголовках рекомендуется использовать кавычки «ёлочки».
Звездочки не нужны (курсив в этом поле не работает).

Я знаю, что **слово "галактика"** пишется с маленькой буквы, если после стоит название **г**алактики: *галактика Млечный Путь, галактика GN-z11.* (точка)

**Но!**

*Размер нашей **г**алактики Млечный Путь 107 000 св. лет.* (без запятых)

Добавила бы метки "орфография" и "названия".